# Signing upgrades w/o Certification Authority

Tags: installshield, digital-signature, installscript

Can I have my InstallScript upgrades signed so that when an upgrade is taking place some validation will take place that the installed application and the upgrade both have the same signature.

I know I can use certification authority but I need to do it with out.
I know that there are cheap certification but this is not about the money.

Answer (score 1):

Validation from inside your code makes no sense. The only reliable validation is the one built into the outside entity, i.e. the OS. In Windows such mechanism is named Authenticode, and it involves certificates, issued by Certificate Authorities. Similar mechanisms exist for Java, for Adobe scripting stuff and for Office scripts, yet all of them use certificates. So your (most likely the only) option is to get some cheap Code Signing certificates from one of CAs.